# Server 2008 SP1 VSS Writers Not Responding

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss, backup

I've got a Windows Server 08 box on SP1 that is having some problems.  We've experienced backup problems and I've traced it down to VSS Writers not responding.  From the command line, if I type vssadmin list providers, I get

> Provider name: 'Microsoft Software Shadow Copy provider 1.0'
> Provider type: System
> Provider Id: {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}
> Version: 1.0.0.7

If I type vssadmin list writers, I get this

> vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
> (C) Copyright 2001-2005 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Waiting for responses.
> These may be delayed if a shadow copy is being prepared.

I could wait this out for hours and it won't move.

I looked up how Server 2008 handles VSS writers, and you can't reregister them like you could in Server 2003
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/062cc52c-899b-45f3-8d0c-798b92363f41

Does anyone know how to fix something like this or where to turn next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the answer is to re-register the vss writers using the following batch file on this particular server.

net stop "System Event Notification Service"
net stop "Background Intelligent Transfer Service"
net stop "COM+ Event System"
net stop "Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider"
net stop "Volume Shadow Copy"
cd /d %windir%\system32
net stop vss
net stop swprv
regsvr32 /s ATL.DLL
regsvr32 /s comsvcs.DLL
regsvr32 /s credui.DLL
regsvr32 /s CRYPTNET.DLL
regsvr32 /s CRYPTUI.DLL
regsvr32 /s dhcpqec.DLL
regsvr32 /s dssenh.DLL
regsvr32 /s eapqec.DLL
regsvr32 /s esscli.DLL
regsvr32 /s FastProx.DLL
regsvr32 /s FirewallAPI.DLL
regsvr32 /s kmsvc.DLL
regsvr32 /s lsmproxy.DLL
regsvr32 /s MSCTF.DLL
regsvr32 /s msi.DLL
regsvr32 /s msxml3.DLL
regsvr32 /s ncprov.DLL
regsvr32 /s ole32.DLL
regsvr32 /s OLEACC.DLL
regsvr32 /s OLEAUT32.DLL
regsvr32 /s PROPSYS.DLL
regsvr32 /s QAgent.DLL
regsvr32 /s qagentrt.DLL
regsvr32 /s QUtil.DLL
regsvr32 /s raschap.DLL
regsvr32 /s RASQEC.DLL
regsvr32 /s rastls.DLL
regsvr32 /s repdrvfs.DLL
regsvr32 /s RPCRT4.DLL
regsvr32 /s rsaenh.DLL
regsvr32 /s SHELL32.DLL
regsvr32 /s shsvcs.DLL
regsvr32 /s /i swprv.DLL
regsvr32 /s tschannel.DLL
regsvr32 /s USERENV.DLL
regsvr32 /s vss_ps.DLL
regsvr32 /s wbemcons.DLL
regsvr32 /s wbemcore.DLL
regsvr32 /s wbemess.DLL
regsvr32 /s wbemsvc.DLL
regsvr32 /s WINHTTP.DLL
regsvr32 /s WINTRUST.DLL
regsvr32 /s wmiprvsd.DLL
regsvr32 /s wmisvc.DLL
regsvr32 /s wmiutils.DLL
regsvr32 /s wuaueng.DLL
sfc /SCANFILE=%windir%\system32\catsrv.DLL
sfc /SCANFILE=%windir%\system32\catsrvut.DLL
sfc /SCANFILE=%windir%\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
net start "COM+ Event System"
net start "System Event Notification Service"
net start "Background Intelligent Transfer Service"
net start "Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider"
net start "Volume Shadow Copy"

Comment: Yes!  I had a Windows 10 PC in with "vssadmin list writers" hanging for the last couple of years, and your solution is the one that worked.  (I didn't need to do the "sfc" lines for this particular system.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stopping and starting the volume shadow copy service on the server?
Re-registering the writers may help.

Comment: Hi ServerFaulter.  I've done as requested.  Still get the same output after restarting the volume shadow copy service.